# Submit and redirect using POST method in form in ReactJs

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, forms, get

I want to submit a sign up form from reactjs front-end to SQL via nodejs. GET method is working but POST method is not working.

Following is my code using POST:
**form**

```
<form action='/mainApp' method='POST' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="signUpForm">
    .
    .
    .
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Sign Up
    </button>
</form>
```

**handleSubmit**

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    .
    .
    .
    handdleData();
    if (firstNameValidation && lastNameValidation && emailValidation && passwordValidation && confirmPasswordValidation && SQLValidation) {
        document.getElementById("signUpForm").submit();
    }
}
```

**handleData**

```
handleData = async (url) => {
    const newData = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id_: this.state.id,
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
        }),
    }).then(res => res.json());

    console.log('newData-', newData);
    return newData;
}
```

**server.js**

```
app.post('/mainApp/insert', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Insert called');
    const result = await dbOperation.showVals('email', req.body.email);
    console.log(result.rows.length);
    if (result.rows.length > 0) {
        console.warn('Duplicate email address');
        res.send({ errorPresent: true, errorMessage: 'Duplicate email address' });
    } else {
        console.log('Inserting', req.body.id_, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.email, req.body.password);
        await dbOperation.insertVals(req.body.id_, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.email, req.body.password);
        res.send({ errorPresent: false, errorMessage: 'No error' });
    }
});
```

I have done the same thing using GET method without the body and changing POST to GET and it works.

Comment: You'll need to share more of the code around your server.js, I presume this is using expressJS. Are you getting a 404 or some other error?

Comment: Please provide the problem more specifically. For example, the server is not receiving the request or there is not data in the body.

Comment: What is this `handleData` about? It doesn't seem to be used anywhere (at least in the code you show)  And your form is posting to `action='/mainApp'` but the only route on the backend you show is `app.post('/mainApp/insert', ...`